# getting a mouse device handle from a device interface

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10

I have a system in which several (physical) mice are present. The code is written in C# on a Windows 10 platform. At any given time, I'd like to be able to filter input from all mice except the one I choose. in order to do that, I want to:

1. use a dictionary/hashtable to hold all the mouse devices in the system, where the key is the mouse device handle, and the value is some humanly readable description of it. I can than, for example, populate a combo-box with those descriptions and choose the mouse I want to use.
2. also, when a mouse is clicked (any mouse), I want to know which mouse was it, in other words I want to know the device handle of the last mouse that was clicked.

I used the wonderful examples given on http://www.pinvoke.net with some slight variations.

i can do (2), and i can almost do (1), but something seems to be missing.
this is how i do (2):

```
    public int GetDeviceID(Message message, out ushort button, out ushort data)
    {
        uint dwSize = 0;

        GetRawInputData(
            message.LParam,
            RID_INPUT,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            ref dwSize,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RawInputHeader))
        );

        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)dwSize);

        GetRawInputData(
            message.LParam,
            RID_INPUT,
            buffer,
            ref dwSize,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RawInputHeader))
        );

        RawInput raw = (RawInput)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(RawInput));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        button = (ushort)raw.Mouse.ButtonFlags;
        data = raw.Mouse.ButtonData;
        if (raw.Header.dwType == (int)RawInputType.Mouse)
        {
            return (int)raw.Header.hDevice;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

and here's how i tried to do (1):

```
    private void GetDevices()
    {
        Guid MouseGUID = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MOUSE;

        // We start at the "root" of the device tree and look for all
        // devices that match the interface GUID of a mouse
        IntPtr h = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref MouseGUID, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (int)(DIGCF.DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF.DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE));
        if (h.ToInt32() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            bool Success = true;
            uint i = 0;
            while (Success)
            {
                // create a Device Interface Data structure
                SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA dia = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
                dia.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(dia);

                // start the enumeration
                Success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(h, IntPtr.Zero, ref MouseGUID, i++, ref dia);
                if (Success)
                {
                    // build a DevInfo Data structure
                    SP_DEVINFO_DATA da = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
                    da.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(da);

                    // build a Device Interface Detail Data structure
                    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA didd = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA();
                    didd.cbSize = 4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize; // trust me :)

                    // now we can get some more detailed information
                    uint nRequiredSize = 0;
                    uint nBytes = BUFFER_SIZE;
                    if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(h, ref dia, ref didd, nBytes, ref nRequiredSize, ref da))
                    {
                        // get the Device Description and DriverKeyName.
                        // what i actually want is the device handle...
                        uint RequiredSize;
                        uint RegType;
                        byte[] ptrBuf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        IntPtr intPtrBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(ptrBuf.Length);

                        if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(h, ref da, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, out RegType, ptrBuf, BUFFER_SIZE, out RequiredSize))
                        {
                            Marshal.Copy(ptrBuf, 0, intPtrBuf, (int)RequiredSize);
                            string ControllerDeviceDesc = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(intPtrBuf);
                            //...

                        }
                        if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(h, ref da, SPDRP_DRIVER, out RegType, ptrBuf, BUFFER_SIZE, out RequiredSize))
                        {
                            Marshal.Copy(ptrBuf, 0, intPtrBuf, (int)RequiredSize);
                            string ControllerDriverKeyName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(intPtrBuf);
                            //...
                        }

                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intPtrBuf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(h);
    }
```

i cannot find any way to get from the SetupDiXXX functions and their output, to a device handle. the closest thing i can see is SP_DEVINFO_DATA.devInst, but that's just an opaque handle to the device instance, so not really useful.
i also looked through the list of Device registry property codes (SPDRP), but non of the codes refer to the device handle.

thanks :)

Comment: What kind of app are you developing? An uwp app or wpf?

Comment: it's a desktop application. it could use either winforms or wpf